# Grafana consolidate pod metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I have a Kubernetes Pod which serves metrics for prometheus.

Once in a while I update the release and thus the pod gets restarted.

Prometheus safes the metrics but labels it according to the new pod name:

[image]

this is by prometheus' design, so its ok.

but if I display this data with grafana, Im getting this (the pods ahve been redeployed twice):

[image]

So for example the metric "Registered Users" now has 3 different colors because the source from it comes from 3 diffferent pods

I have some options. Maybe disregard the pod name in prometheus, but I consider that bad practise because I dont want to lose data.

So I think I have to consolidate this in grafana. But how I can I tell Grafana that I want to merge all data with container-name `api-gateway-narkuma` and disregard the label `pods`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
max(users) without (instance, pod)
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a solution! Dou you want to elaborate, or point to somewhere for me to understand that query?

Comment: or is there a way to apply that for all incoming data so i dont have to repeat myself for every graph?

Comment: > without removes the listed labels from the result vector, while all other labels are preserved in the output. by does the opposite and drops labels that are not listed in the by clause, even if their label values are identical between all elements of the vector.

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/

Comment: afaik you’ll need to do that in each graph unless you change how the data is recorded originally